# How to print only a part of a helper array in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor helper returning an array. So, "King" is an array:

```
....
<p>{{King}}</p>
...
```

What I'd like to do is print just the nth element in the array at different places in a template. Something like:

```
<p>{{King}}[0] here</p>
...
<li>{{King}}[4]  here</li>
...
```

I tried using 
    {{#each King}}
    {{#if King...?}} // Don't know how it would be written. Can I do this?

Here's my helper:

```
Template.clientGrid.helpers({
  'King': function() {
    var arrayFullName = Session.get('clientName');
    var grid = Demographic.find({ "Fname": arrayFullName[0], "Lname":    arrayFullName[1] }).map(function (a) { return (a.Code + " " + a.Fname); });
    grid = grid[0].split(" ");
    console.log(grid); // prints ["FAC", "GEORGE"]
    return grid;
```

}
});

Answer (score 0):

Close. You're looking to use `{{King[n]}}`, where `n` is the index in the array.

Comment: For me {{King[n]}} seems to be printing the whole array.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just printing the object located at that index in the array?